# Elegant solution to show bash alias value

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, alias

Like everyone who uses `*nix` shells, I have a significant number of `alias`es and I frequently forget the details of an `alias` I'm using.

Possibly this is laziness, but reducing keystrokes and command executions increases my productivity. So I'm looking for a clean solution that does the below, ***for every alias I have defined*** in my `bash4` environment.

---

Alias defined as:
`alias l='ls -laH'`

Desired additional alias to be created before entering in the shell:
`alias l?='alias l'`

Desired results:
`$ l?
alias l='ls -laH'`

---

The format is always `"{alias_name}?"`

The goal is not to have to create an individual `"help"` alias for every alias. I *could* iterate, but that seems clunky to me.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this without iteration.  The closest would be to make `?` an alias for `alias`, so you could do  e.g. `? l`.

Comment: Good suggestion and perhaps I could add autocomplete to the ?. I was hoping for something similar to a lambda expression but I suppose that's no different than a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `bash` 4, you can take advantage of the `command_not_found_handle` hook:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    if [[ $1 =~ .*\? ]]; then
        alias ${1%?}
    else
        printf "Command not found: $1\n"
        return 127
    fi
}
```

However, `?` is a poor choice for the suffix to use, since it is the shell pattern metacharacter that matches any single character. For example, if there is a file in the current directory that matches `l?` (say, `la`), then the shell will attempt to run `la` rather than `l?`, and your custom alias hook will not run. You could disable globbing with `set -f`, but invoking your alias hook with `l\?` would probably be better.

Another option would be to use `@`—for "@lias" :)—instead of `?` as the suffix to trigger the hook, as `@` is unlikely to occur in any command name and is not a shell metacharacter.

Comment: Hey, Bash 4 has AUTOLOAD/method_missing? I somehow missed that.  Thanks!

Comment: That is a truly elegant solution. I realize `?` is a poor choice, was surprised it worked any way. The `@` is a good suggestion. Nicely done @chepner

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** If you're using Bash 4, you can use the `command_not_found_handle` to do this, as suggested by chepner below.  I would accept that answer in lieu of mine.

If you're stuck with Bash <=3, though, I fear the best you can do is iterate, with something like this:

```
 for a in $(alias | sed 's/alias \([^=]*\)=.*/\1/'); do alias "${a}?"="alias '$a'"; done
```

(Pick your favorite way of extracting the alias names out of the alias output..)

To avoid that, the closest thing I can think of would be to make `?` itself an alias (or some other character; as chepner also notes, `?` is a single-character wildcard, which can make the contents of your current working directory randomly blow up your alias).  You could make it an alias for `alias` itself, so you could do e.g. `? l` instead of `l?`, with simply `alias \?=alias`. As you said, autocomplete might make that nicer, which you could do with `complete -a \?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just type `alias` in the command prompt

```
$ alias l
alias l='ls -laH'
```

Note: invoking `alias` without argument will display *every alias that is currently defined*

Answer (score 0):

I think MarkReed's `?` as alias/function solution is a fairly elegant one.

Something like:

```
alias ?=alias
complete -a ?
```

or:

```
?() {
    for arg; do
        if [ "$(type -t "$arg")" = alias ]; then
            alias "$arg"
        else
            echo "No such alias: $arg"
        fi
    done
}
complete -a ?
```

With the function (and bash 4) you could even then keep an aliasinfo associative array with more usage/help/etc. information about each alias and then echo that out too.

```
?() {
    for arg; do
        printf %s "${aliasinfo[$arg]:+"$aliasinfo[$arg]"$'\n'}"
        if [ "$(type -t "$arg")" = alias ]; then
            alias "$arg"
        else
            echo "No such alias: $arg"
        fi
    done
}
```

And then when you define an alias you do something like this:

```
aliasinfo[l]="Full long directory listing"
alias l='ls -laH'
```